# Because the algorithm is known, it is no longer a trade secret

Tags: rc4

In wiki about RC4 cipher they said,

> Because the algorithm is known, it is no longer a trade secret.

Is that mean the cipher text will be more secure if the algorithm unknown to the attacker.

About AES is it really full paper public so anyone with knowledge can read how its work or there is something hidden

Comment: The question is mostly rhetorical. Also it is not about "algorithm-design", much less "algebraic-attack" as tagged. The question asked formally seems to be: "does the quoted text mean that cipher text will be more secure if the algorithm is unknown to the attacker?", and the answer is obviously: no, the quoted text does not mean or imply that. The quoted text exposes a fact following from the legal definition of trade secret in US law, nothing more; it has nothing to do with cryptography.

Comment: The quote is about the legal status of trade secret, not about the security of some algorithm. In general, have a look at [Kerkhoffs's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question: Are ciphertexts produced by secret (unknown to the public) algorithms more secure than those produced by public algorithms like AES?

Answer: No. The reverse! Public algorithms (like AES) have been examined by professional cryptographers all over the world. In contrast, secret algorithms, by definition, have not been subject to that process at all — so why would you think those algorithms could possibly more secure than public ones?

Comment: I don't think you can definitively say no, secret algorithms are not more secure.

Comment: But how come hide encryption system didnt improve security, if you dont know the system you have totally random letters it must increase security? as u need to know the system then find the key ??? i'm a little new in encryption just read about and hope to design my hand cipher

Comment: @illsecure, there is a field of study called cryptanalysis that is about studying the "totally random letters" and unscrambling them.  Enigma, the very complex electromechanical rotor system used by the Germans in WWII, was an unknown system yet was broken by the Allies.

Comment: @John Deters: To be fair and accurate, Enigma was not broken because it was a weak algorithm, it was broken because it was not implimented correctly(human error).

Comment: @JohnDeters: Enigma was NOT "an unknown system" for its cryptanalysts; they had access to the design. Sometime, when unknown rotors have been introduced, that blocked cryptanalysis.

Comment: The NSA has several secret ciphers, called SUITE A (BATON being one of the most well known). SUITE A ciphers (not publicly revealed) are considered the most secure by the NSA (although a few type 1 ciphers are public). That is not to say the ciphers have not be subject to review, many many cryptographers work for the NSA and have attempted to break these ciphers. That being said, I'd still prefer AES256 to BATON if my life depended on it. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BATON 

http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/crypto/2000-q4/0028.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSA_Suite_A_Cryptography

Comment: @fgrieu, yes, they knew it was a rotor system, but the Biuro Szyfrów did not initially know the wiring of the rotors in use by Germany. Rejewski determined those mathematically.  And yes, William Hird, a poor implementation aided him in that cryptanalysis, as well as improving the efficiency of new key recoveries.

Comment: @WilliamHird there were weaknesses in the system itself that were exploitable, e.g. the fact that no letter could encrypt to itself aided the placing of probable plaintext, and the specifics of the stepping (which was too regular) also implied the Stecker-settings could be separated from the wheel settings if probable plaintext was known. The allied rotor systems (Typex, SIGABA) did not suffer from such weaknesses. Human errors played a role (the weak indicator system in the beginning of WW II, stereotypical text) but were IMHO not even the most essential.

Comment: @Henno: I will just quote from the Wikipedia article on this matter: "Although Enigma had some cryptographic weaknesses, in practice it was only in combination with proceedural flaws, operator mistakes, captured key tables and hardware, that Allied cryptanalysts were able to be so successful." I might also like to add that I don't believe the official Bletchley Park story about how they "broke the code". Its too "pat", too "Hollywood", of course we will never really know what happened. Finis. :-)